# C++ Write line from text file to new file. Copies previews line not current line

Tags: c++

I have a loop the reads through my text file and when it finds a match for my condition I want it to print that line to a new text file. My code works it is just printing the preview line not the current, and it keeps over writing onto the first line of the text file.

```
void FileManager::copyLine(std::string newLine)
{
    line1 = newLine;
    std::ofstream outFile("temp.txt");

    outFile << line1 << std::endl;
    outFile.close();
}

if (p1.getPos() == "WR")
        {
            if (line2.getPosWR1().empty())
            {
                line2.setWR1_Pos(p1.getPos());
                line2.setWR1_Name(p1.getName());
                line2.setWR1_Salary(p1.getSal());
                line2.setWR1_Projection(p1.getProj());
                file1.copyLine(line);
                wr1++;
            }
            else if (!line2.getPosWR1().empty() && line2.getPosWR2().empty())
            {
                line2.setWR2_Pos(p1.getPos());
                line2.setWR2_Name(p1.getName());
                line2.setWR2_Salary(p1.getSal());
                line2.setWR2_Projection(p1.getProj());
                file1.copyLine(line);
                wr2++;
            }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. It's very hard for us to tell what's going on and what the problem might be without more context.

Comment: Also take this as an opportunity to learn how to use a *debugger*, and how to use it to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: I am guessing I just need to go to endof file than print.

Comment: If you used a debugger no guessing would be needed. Meaning step through the code 1 line at a time looking at the variables at each step to see what is happening.

Comment: With the currently selected file open modes the file stream makes a new empty file and replaces the existing file. Consult the options given in the [constructor's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) for how to append to an existing file.

Comment: We can't really help with this because there are a lot of missing parts. We don't know much about any of the variables or how they get their values.

Comment: ...or the loop which I thought you don’t have but looks like you do.

Comment: One other thing to watch out for is the [Working Directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). Depending on how and where you run the program, it may not look for "temp.txt" where you want it to look.

Answer (score 1):

New to stack overflow :D but I found the my answer this is the change I made so simple!

```
std::ofstream outFile("temp.txt", std::ios::app);
```

I just had to add the ios::app. to append to the end of the file.